# How do I fix this DateTime object to work in my query?

Tags: datetime, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a private method in a controller and when I run the method and try echo out the results in my browser, it just dies. I get a white screen with no profiler on the bottom and nothing shows up in my error_log.

Here is my complete method. Note the "hello" does not echo out so it appears to die at the query. Also note that the 'created' field in the table is a datetime type.

```
private function garbageCollect()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dql = 'SELECT r FROM AppBundle:MyEntity r WHERE r.created < :created';

    $created = new \DateTime('-50 days');
    $result = $em->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameters( array( 'created' => $created->format('Y-m-d') ) )
        ->getResult();
    echo "hello"; die; // it never echoes this out so it fails above

    ... // more code here excluded

    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UPDATE: my log fiile shows the following as the WHERE clause:  WHERE r0_.created < ? ["2016-07-22"] []

Comment: UPDATE 2: Changing the parameters to: ->setParameters( array( 'created' => new \DateTime() ) ) will still cause the page to die after 6 seconds of attempting to execute the query. Still getting a white page with no output, no html, nothing. Log files are still empty. The dev.log for Symfony shows the query which executes fine in phpmyadmin. Changing the created field out with something like 'id' < :id and putting an integer for the id in the params lets the query run fine and page outputs. WTH?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format the date object as a string. If the field named created is defined as a Doctrine DateTime, you could simply do:

```
$created = new \DateTime('-50 days');
    $result = $em->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameters( array( 'created' => $created ) )
        ->getResult();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Even if I change the params to ->setParameters( array( 'created' => new \DateTime() ) ) , the page still dies after 6 seconds with no output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to everyone who took time to look or comment on this and I appreciate the time you took. It appears that Symfony was consuming all my memory allocated to PHP so I had to bump it up considerably. Now it seems to be working fine. The table was rather large it seems. Thanks!